# Show last login date on form as dd/mm/yyyy or 12-February-2014

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Greetings to you all!

Please I need suggestion on how to format my Php form to show last login date on form as dd/mm/yyyy or 12-February-2014. I want my form to print to the user saying: **Hello and Welcome ! Your last login is dd/mm/yyyy or 12-February-2014**. The last login here is the very login session he/she is in.

I am using MySQL as backend database but like you know MySQL captures date as yyyy/mm/dd but I dont want it shown that way when the user logins in.

How can I handle this please?

Thank you in advance.

Mike

Comment: http://in1.php.net/datetime

Comment: @user3201606 Please let me know if my answer worked for you. Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered

Comment: @DhruvJoshi: I will do so. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySql DATE_FORMAT FUNCTION >> `DATE_FORMAT(your_date,'%d %b %y')`

for example,

`DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%d %b %y')` gives you  21 Feb 14

OR

`DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')` gives you  21-2-2014

Comment: Can you tell me how I can apply it to Dreamweaver form

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Use like

```
   echo date("d/F/Y",$datevar);
```

or

```
   echo date("d-F-Y",$datevar);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how I can apply to Dreamweaver form

Comment: You can add it as code. See link here http://www.ehow.com/how_8499005_embed-php-html-dreamweaver.html